# "Restart to complete updates" message remains after reboot

Tags: reboot

No matter how many times I restart my computer I keep getting this message "Restart to complete updates".

Can you please suggest what to look for and how to fix the problem?

Comment: Please confirm which **Ubuntu** version.  Have you opened a terminal session and run: **sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade** ?  What (if any) errors are shown?

Comment: Does it allow you to login?

Answer (score 2):

There is a magic file. If it exists, this signals that a reboot is needed. Its path is:
`/var/run/reboot-required`

Try to delete that file as root and tell us whether it is possible to delete it.
If it is possible to delete it, check whether the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get clean` first. Then do `sudo apt-get update` && `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

Install Synaptic Package Manager then search there for "update manager" and reinstall it.